# How to upload an image without senKeys input in selenium webdriver using javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.css('div.border-right:nth- child(2)')), 1000)
.then((element) => {
element.click();
});
```

The above code is up to clicked the image upload button. After that i don't know how to select the specific image/file to get upload.

Comment: Why do you have space in this selector -- `nth- child(2)`?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `sendKeys()`? Have a look at [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)

Comment: While typing i made this mistake. But there is no space in this selector --> nth-child(2).

Comment: Because input tag had a style as display:none. when i tried sendKeys() elementNotInteractable error came. How will I make the input display block and i wanted to use send keys. I am using linux machine, so autolt is not supporting